# How can i read the filename from jsp and use that as a src for image?

Tags: html, jsp

```
<%
    System.out.println("Content Type ="+request.getContentType());
String fileBasePath = "c:/temp"; //Base path where you wanto store the files...
    DiskFileUpload fu = new DiskFileUpload();
    fu.setSizeMax(100000000);

    List fileItems = fu.parseRequest(request);
    Iterator itr = fileItems.iterator();

try{
    while(itr.hasNext()) {
      FileItem fi = (FileItem)itr.next();

      if(!fi.isFormField()) {
            File fNew= new File(fileBasePath, new File(fi.getName()).getName());
        System.out.println(fNew.getAbsolutePath());
        fi.write(fNew);
      }
      else {
        System.out.println("Field ="+fi.getFieldName());
      }
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}

%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `Servlet` which gets the image as `InputStream` and writes it to the `OutputStream` of the response and then call that servlet in the `<img src>`.

E.g.

```
<img src="imageservlet/name.gif" />
```

with

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File("c:/temp", request.getPathInfo()));
OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
// Write input to output.
```

A basic example can be found [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/04/imageservlet.html).